# Using jq output within json2csv

Tags: jq

i would like to use the output of jq as input for json2csv (https://github.com/jehiah/json2csv).
By using the following command, i´m getting the expected output on the screen: `<import5.json jq -c`

But how can i use this output for another command (e.g. json2csv)? Is there a chance to safe the ouput to a file or even nicer using the output directly within json2csv?
I tried 
`<import5.json jq -c | json2csv value,timestamp -o output.csv` to use the output of jq as input for json2csv.
Also i tried `<import5.json jq -c >ouput.json` to safe the output to a file.

I´m a total newbie in this field and would appreciate any help

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Here is how my input looks like:
{
"One": "Result",
"Two": 3,
"three": 4000,
},
{
"One": "B",
"Two": 1,
"three": 9088,
}

My expected output would be a csv file which includes the data, one line should look like that "One",Two","three".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the jq filter explicitly, along the lines of:

```
jq -c . INPUTFILE | json2csv ...
```

or:

```
<INPUTFILE jq -c . | json2csv ...
```

By the way, chances are you can accomplish whatever you're trying to do using json2csv by using features of jq. For example, have you looked at @csv?

Comment: There is a good cance that it is possible to get what i want just using jq. I would like to convert my json input into a csv file.

Comment: With changing my command to: '<import5.json jq -c .| json2csv -k one,two -o output.csv' it is working as long as the input is consisting of just one instance of the json file. But as soon as there are two or more instances there is a problem with the comma in between the instances. when i delete the comma in the input file by hand, it is working.